# How to configure a layer-3 switch for routing between VLANs?

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan

I have set up the router as a dhcp server and I would like to use the layer 3 switch to route each PC in seperate vlans. How do I configure the router and L3 switch for inter vlan routing ?

the router config:

```
Current configuration : 787 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.1.0.1
!
ip dhcp pool 1
 network 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 10.1.0.1
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524W57G-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

L3 switch config :

```
Current configuration : 1244 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip routing
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.1.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the router and switch configurations. The answer depends on the existing configurations, and we have no idea about that.

Comment: Where are the VLANs that you want to route between?

Comment: I only created vlan 1 in the L3 switch and assigned an ip address to that interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To route on the layer-3 switch:

1. IP routing needs to be enabled on the L3 switch (`ip routing`, it is by default on a 3560).
2. VLANs need to be created and assigned to end-node ports in access mode.
3. IP addresses need to be assigned to each VLAN interface (SVI) - via DHCP would work, but static addresses are preferred.
4. The SVIs must not be in `shutdown`.

Another option is to route between VLANs on the router which also works with a layer-2 switch. The port towards the router needs to use trunk mode with all required VLANs allowed, and on the router you'd use VLAN subinterfaces to connect each VLAN.

A layer-3 switch is usually much better suited for inter-VLAN routing since it's generally hardware-based, causes no additional forwarding delays, and avoids the switch-router interconnect bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Routing is enabled on the switch by default. So place your interfaces (fa0/2 and fa0/3) in the proper VLANs and that’s all you need to do.

The interfaces connected to the PCs should be access mode, not trunk